# How do I 'inject' common code to various js functions?

Tags: javascript, insert

I am building a quizzing system and questions, in JS, have common code (second line to //more stuff):

```
 let qId = 1000003, // question ID number, unique to this question
        uId = QWIZM.state.uId,
        sd = QWIZM.methods.toSigDigs,
        stringify = QWIZM.methods.stringify,
        sin = utils.sin,
        cos = utils.cos,
        asin = utils.asin,
        acos = utils.acos,
        tan = utils.tan,
        atan = utils.atan,
        thisQuiz = QWIZM.state.thisQuiz,
        ov = QWIZM.methods.overlayVariable,
        seed = qId > uId ? qId % uId : uId === qId ? uId : uId % qId,
        lcrng = new utils.LCRNG(seed);

// more stuff here
```

How can I insert the common code so I my file looks like this:

```
let qId = 1000003, // question ID number, unique to this question
commonToAll();
// more stuff here
```

Of course, it doesn't need to be a function...

Comment: Build the common code in a file and export it. Import it wherever required

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into that. I didn't realise you can import 'anywhere' rather than at the top of the file. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use ES6 Modules to accomplish that.
Mozilla has a pretty comprehensive explanation on MDN:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Modules